# Multi Line Text Box Displays HTML Elements When Going Back To Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `asp.net` web form which on one page has a multi line `textbox`.  When the user types in this field and continues the details are displayed on a confirmation page and displays as the user entered

**Example**

*This is the first line*

*This is the second line*

But when I click my edit button (which directs me back to my page) my `textbox` displays as

`This is the first line<br /><br />This is the second line`

I want it to keep its styling but don't know how to do this.  The details are stored in the session.

**Code behind**

```
protected void Step07SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Step07OtherDetailsField"] = Step07OtherDetailsField.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
    Response.Redirect("/Quotation/pg3.aspx");
}
```

I tried the following in my `Page_Load`

```
Step07OtherDetailsField.Text.Replace("<br />", "\r\n");
```

and also

```
Step07OtherDetailsField.Text.Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine);
```

But for some reason when I debug it, it says that my `.text` is empty but the previous wording is actually still displayed in the field and the `<br />` is also still displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to replace anything. You just store value in session and display it to any textbox, it will maintain \r and \t.

If you want to display result in span then display result to textbox with multiline then apply css for no border,etc.

Comment: I need to replace so that on my confirmation page it displays as the user entered it and is readable to them but as I said when I click my edit button (so the user can update it), it displays the `<br />`

Comment: on your confirmation page this text is displayed on span or textbox?

Comment: If you want to display it on span then you have to replace other wise you bind value in textbox as it.

Comment: On my confirmation page it is displayed in a `<div>`

Comment: I think you should display text in to textarea readonly in your confirmation page. so no need to replace words.

Comment: Ok so if I am to use a readonly `textbox`, how do I get the text to display on my confirmation page as the details entered in previous page are stored in my session

Comment: textbox.text=session["name"].tostring();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107734/discussion-between-murday1983-and-vimal-vataliya).